# NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Tags: python, unicode, nameerror

```
fileMain = open("dictionary_15k.txt", "r")
for line1 in fileMain:
    dictWords.append(unicode(line1.strip(), "utf-8"))
```

When compiled it shows

```
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

Comment: @Signal: no, and if this was Python 2, they wouldn't have to because it is a built-in. The OP evidently is using Python 3 to run Python 2 code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wow, thank you for that.

Answer (score 28):

There is no such name in Python 3, no. You are trying to run Python 2 code in Python 3. In Python 3, `unicode` has been renamed to `str`.

However, you can remove the `unicode()` call altogether; `open()` produces a file object that *already* decodes data to Unicode for you. You probably want to tell it what codec to use, explicitly:

```
fileMain = open("dictionary_15k.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
for line1 in fileMain:
    dictWords.append(line1.strip())
```

You may want to switch to Python 2 if your tutorial is written with that version in mind.